# Have a link Appear based on a condition MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way for me to make a link appear on an MVC2 page based on a condition (to be exact, whether a user is in a role?)

**UPDATE: some more information**

Generally speaking I don't have anything yet... I was just wondering what the best way to go about doing this was...

I want the link to show up here in the site.Master

```
     <ul id="menu">
                <%
                    if(true){}
                     %>              
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>                   
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("View Your Populations", "PopulationInfo", "PatientACO")%></li>                    
     </ul>
```

Comment: Hi, there are many ways... can you show what you tried so far and how you view with the link you want to hide or show looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a Model for each page view that has a `UserIsInRole` property (or whatever), and then you just check it and show the link based on that.

```
<ul id="menu">
                <%
                    if(true){}
                     %>              
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>     
                <% if (Model != null && Model.UserIsInRole()) { %>              
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("View Your Populations", "PopulationInfo", "PatientACO")%></li>           
                <% } %>
     </ul>
```

**EDIT:**

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public bool UserIsInRole {get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.UserIsInRole = User.IsInRole("Role");
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

View:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <% if (Model.UserIsInRole) {
        <li><% Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "NewAction", "NewController") %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sounds like a decent solution.  So, say I had one page that needed to check whether or not I was user in a role.  I would have a property(bool) that would be true if said user is in a role?  How could I check that and change that?

Comment: Couldn't I just check if the user is in the role on the page?
For instance (on my site.master) couldn't I do this...
<% if(user.IsInRole("ACOAdmin") {}; %>

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't have that kind of logic in your views.  What happens when you need to check 2 roles.  You can't unit test the code then if it is in the view.

Comment: Is there a way I can check it without actually having to pass an object to a view?  Because this happens in my site.Master I won't necessarily be passing this object back and forth to the view.